# Altium Designer Rules problem

Tags: pcb, altium, designer

I've got few PCB Rules on my project about trace's width restriction and the problem I face is, when I perform "Import changes" from my design, the rules are always appeared on Engineering Change Order dialog as modify action.
I choose "Execute Changes" and "Done" column are checked but when I try to make "Import Changes" again, I don't see something like "There's no differences" but the same dialog is appeared again with the same Rules on the list.

Comment: Make sure you set it for the whole project. Not only the *.PcbDoc file.

Comment: How can I be sure about that?

Comment: Just click on the whole project on the left pane and set the rules

Comment: I can't find it. I want to set the rules from schematic and add they to PCB doc. But they are constantly apeared on ECO dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on the stack.

To be exact, on the "Edit Rule Values..." The "Load PCB Layer Stack and calculate track..." was pointing on "Default Stack" and I assigned my pcb document there.
I did the same on the rest rules and problem has been solved.

Although, I see again "Default Stack" as previous I don't see rules being modified recurrently when I choose "Import Change from schematic".

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer. To do this, please [accept](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the "tick" icon next to the answer. This indicates to other users that you found the answer useful, and it also stops Stack Exchange from periodically "bumping" your question in the hope of getting an accepted answer. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

Importing changes from the schematic has absolutely nothing to do with the design rules. You have to go in and change the trade widths and then re-run the DRC in order to remove the errors. All the "Import Changes" does is bring in changes from the schematic (connections, component parameters, etc) to the PCB so that the PCB editor knows what connects to what. The rule check is a completely different entity.

Comment: No, I do not want to resolve the errors, I have put some design restrictions on the schematic (http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Adding+Design+Rule+Directives+to+a+Schematic+Document) and I'm trying to transfer them to pcb document. In PCB document, Design->Import Changes from-> Engineering Change Order dialog is apeared and I execute. When I repeat the steps, the same rules are apeared on the ECO dialog list.

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing. I misunderstood completely. There is a reason why proper grammar is important -- run-on sentences are very difficult to follow. Anyway, is there any particular reason you want to add the design rules to the schematic? Why not just add the rules in the PCB editor? Rarely would one need to see PCB design rules when looking at the schematic. The method you're using simply clutters up the schematic with information that doesn't really need to be displayed in most cases.

Comment: It's better and very easy to see the rules on the schematic especially when it contains high current power supplies, DRAMs, etc. Some of my rules do work fine. I managed to execute they and were added to pcb document, but some others are permanent appeared on the ECO dialog and that is a little annoying.